# Rails form url configuration to avoid No route matches [PATCH]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a bit confused, I have admin section in my project. These are the routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
  namespace :admin do
    get '/' => 'dashboard#index'
    resources :dashboard, only: [:index]
    resources :categories do
      collection do
        get :set_active
      end
      resources :sections, only: [:edit, :new, :create, :update]
    end
  end
```

And I have a form.

If I start it like this.

```
<%= form_for @category, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

It fails (because it tries to search bad url without admin).

`undefined method` category_path' for #ActionView::Base:0x00000000019320`

So I defined url.

`<%= form_for @category, url: admin_categories_path do |f| %>`

It works great when i create new category, but if I want to edit the category with the same form partial, it fails:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/categories"
```

but routes exists

```
                        admin_categories GET    /admin/categories(.:format)                                                                       admin/categories#index
                                         POST   /admin/categories(.:format)                                                                       admin/categories#create
                      new_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/new(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#new
                     edit_admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                              admin/categories#edit
                          admin_category GET    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#show
                                         PATCH  /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#update
                                         PUT    /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#update
                                         DELETE /admin/categories/:id(.:format)                                                                   admin/categories#destroy
```

and I have methods in my model for `index, new, create, update, edit, show`.

I have no idea how to set up it properly.

Answer (score 0):

One small detail that is missed `@category` to your route path, so it will build url
`/admin/categories/1` where `1` is `@category.id` Rails builds url from model

```rb
<%= form_for([:admin, @category]) do |f| %>
```

So rails generated route for you `/admin/categories/:id` but you are trying to access `/admin/categories/` with no `:id`

further [reading](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

Comment: I tried this too, but it fails on `No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/categories.5"`

Comment: can you change your routes file `resources :categories do end` just to `resources :categories`

Comment: sorry I copypasted older route file, I have a nested controller, I will edit my question.

Comment: also can you try this one `form_for(@category, url: admin_categories_path)` and the last guess `form_for([:admin, @category])`

Comment: First of this was my first attempt what was not working but `form_for([:admin, @category])` is working. Thanks so much for help! I am new to rails from padrino and I am sometimes confused by some automagic, which is great, but new for me.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you. btw I updated post with correct answer and add API resource that may help you in future